# How to calculate expected time of successive events

Tags: probability

First time posting here. Apologies if this is too basic on not properly asked.
I am trying to solve a puzzle programmatically an the problem is as follows:

We have several individuals who will go successively in an interrogation room. The characteristics of each individual are expressed in three integer values. The first value indicate the amount of time that person will spend in the interrogation room. The second and third values are the numerator and denominator to be used to calculate the probability that that person will give either a truthful answer or complete silence (I interpret this as success vs failure of the event being, the interrogation).

What is asked is to figure out the smallest lexicographical ordering of these people that will give us the smallest expected time to get the answer to our question.

Now it gives an example of an expected outcome of a scenario that I am not able to understand. 
If we get tow people Person A and person B where the characteristics of person A are [10,1,2], in other words (t=10mins,p=0.5) and person B has [5,1,5], in other words (t=5mins,p=0.2), the claim is that if interrogate A before be then we would expect 12.5 minutes to interrogate both but if we interrogated B before A then we would expect 13 minutes and thus the right answer is to interrogate A before B. Can anyone shed some light on how we are getting 12.5 and 13 in this example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose we invite $A$ first.

If $A$ has answered (which has probability $0.5$), interrogation is finished (10 min).

If $A$ didn't give an answer($P=0.5$), then we need to invite $B$, so interrogation will last $10+5 = 15$min.

Expected time (Expectation): $E = 10\cdot 0.5 + 15\cdot 0.5 = 12.5$min

2. Suppose we invite $B$ first.

If $B$ has answered (probability $0.2$), interrogation is finished (5 min).

If $B$ didn't give an answer($P=0.8$), then we need to invite $A$, so interrogation will last $5+10 = 15$min.

Expected time (Expectation): $E = 5\cdot 0.2 + 15\cdot 0.8 = 13$min

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer. Makes sense. I am trying to think how this scales to n people with different times and probabilities. What is the general formula then for n people?

Comment: My edit timed out so I am appending my previous comment: I ran into code that solves this very problem and what they do is divide time by probability and then sort the list by the resulting single value claiming it is the individual expected interrogation time. I am a little confused as to how this individual expectation differs from the one you explained in your answer. I would greatly appreciate it if I got further clarification on this. Thanks!

Comment: @TBadr Quick answer: brute force approach looks bad, you need to find all possible trajectories (this is called Expectation Minimization). Suppose you have three A,B,C with their probabilities of successful interrogation $p_A,p_B,p_C$ and times $t_A,t_B,t_C$. Then for trajectory "A-B-C" expectation will be $p_A*t_A+ (1-p_A)*[p_B*(t_B+t_A) +(1-p_B)*(t_A+t_B+t_C) ]$.

Comment: @TBadr It seems that I can see, how this works for two objects, but at the moment I cannot generalize the rule to arbitrary set. Lets expand the formula for expectation for two-objects trajectories: $$A-B: \ t_A*p_A + (t_A+t_B)*(1-p_A) = t_A + t_B - t_B*p_A.$$  $$B-A: t_B*p_B + (t_A+t_B)*(1-p_B) = t_B + t_A - t_A*p_B $$. Each time something is subtracted from the $t_A + t_B$.  Lets denote this element as $x*p_A*p_B$ in the first case and $y*p_A*p_B$ in the second. We see that the bigger $x$ or $y$ is, the lesser is the expectation. We can obtain this value by dividing $t_i/p_i$ and compare.

Comment: @TBadr However, at the moment I don't see such a good coincidence for the three-object case. So, the hypothetic algorithm can do all the divisions and then order the elements into a some supposed-to-be-optimal chain, but I haven't proved yet that it will be optimal (it seems to be optimal on each step). Do they just order arbitrary number of objects in this way?

Comment: The number of people interrogated ranges from a minimum of two to a maximum of 50. The solution I came across is literally two lines (python using sorted with key). It defines a sorting function that divides the time by the probability of every item in the input array and then it sorts the array based on the function to return the proper ordering of interrogation. This is not the first problem that i encounter that is written in way that sways you towards a brute force solution via examples, while there is a better an more efficient way of implementing the solution. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Not sure if you can read code but the solution can be found here: lines 1 thorugh 16 : https://github.com/richardsheridan/foobar/blob/master/minion_interrogation.py

Comment: I found some explanation of your algorithm, question asked 7 months ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/3oyedw/precalculus_probability_word_problems_and/    

Looks like this is really an optimal solution. You can ask another question about mathematical proof of it, but I believe that this is true, because I have already checked that it is optimal on each step and the calculated value actually depends only on the element itself.

Comment: Wow! great find! Thanks so much for all your help. I have been able to solve the problems i've been given so far on my own but this one's been bugging me because I couldn't even understand the reasoning. Thanks to you I can be at ease now. Cheers!!